# Mock JNI methods in Java

Tags: unit-testing, java-native-interface, powermock, powermockito

I am using PowerMockito and JUnit. How can mock JNI funtions?

```java
Class A{
  public native String test();
}
```

```java
Class Util{
  public static String test() {
    A a = new A();
    return a.test();
  }
}
```

unit test:

```java
Class ATest{
  @Test
  public void test1() {
    A a = PowerMockito.mock(A.class);
    PowerMockito.when(a.test()).thenReturn("test");
    boolean check = Util.test().equals("test")
    assert check == true
  }
}
```

If i run the test, I am getting test is native. How to fix this ?

Comment: Are you sure, you are using Spock, the code looks more like JUnit with groovy.

Comment: In Spock, you can mock a native method like any other method. There is no need for Mockito or PowerMock, you simply use Spock mocks. The only thing you would use an additional mock tool like Mockito, PowerMock or Sarek for would be to mock the static method of your utility class. I would avoid that if I were you, though. Simply refactor the utility class to get the `A` instance injected, either via method parameter or a static member with a setter method. Then you can simply inject a normal mock and be happy without additional fancy tools covering up your bad application design. Go refactor!

Comment: Furthermore, you use PowerMock in the wrong way: You are creating a mock, but not injecting it into the static method, same problem as described above. You would have to stub constructor calls too, making sure that the constructor returns your mock. All of this is the result of the bad design decision to create your dependency instance as a local variable inside a method, making the code tightly rather than loosely coupled, which also impedes testability. You can solve that with PowerMock, if you insist, but having to use that tool at all is a bad smell already.

Comment: Forgot to post my findings yesterday here. @kriegaex was right. I missed mocking the constructor. That has solved the issue. I used mock because I had to verify the method invocation.

Comment: Then please write a comprehensive answer, showing the code solving your problem, for everyone's benefit. You asked the community for help, now you have a chance to return something to same community. Please also do consider to refactor your (nearly) untestable static helper method. Believe me, your life as a developer will be much better after you will have said goodbye to PowerMock.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to get rid of PowerMock and refactor your code as follows. I used a native method from an example project I found somewhere, not exactly your example, but you get the idea:

```java
package com.baeldung.jni;

public class HelloWorldJNI {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("native");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HelloWorldJNI().sayHello();
  }

  public native String sayHello();
}
```

```cpp
#include "com_baeldung_jni_HelloWorldJNI.h"
#include <iostream>

/*
 * Class:     com_baeldung_jni_HelloWorldJNI
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_baeldung_jni_HelloWorldJNI_sayHello (JNIEnv* env, jobject thisObject) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++ !!";
    std::cout << hello << std::endl;
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q68949748;

import com.baeldung.jni.HelloWorldJNI;

public class Util {
  private static HelloWorldJNI helloWorld = new HelloWorldJNI();

  public static void setHelloWorld(HelloWorldJNI helloWorld) {
    Util.helloWorld = helloWorld;
  }

  public static void doSomethingUseful() {
    System.out.println(helloWorld.sayHello());
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q68949748

import com.baeldung.jni.HelloWorldJNI
import spock.lang.Specification

class BaledungJNITest extends Specification {
  def "verify original native method"() {
    given:
    HelloWorldJNI helloWorld = new HelloWorldJNI()

    expect:
    helloWorld.sayHello() == "Hello from C++ !!"
  }

  def "mock native method"() {
    given:
    HelloWorldJNI helloWorld = Mock() {
      sayHello() >> "mocked"
    }

    expect:
    helloWorld.sayHello() == "mocked"
  }

  def "inject mock into utility class"() {
    given:
    HelloWorldJNI helloWorld = Mock()
    Util.setHelloWorld(helloWorld)

    when:
    Util.doSomethingUseful()

    then:
    1 * helloWorld.sayHello() >> "mocked"
  }

}
```

The console log would be:

```
Hello from C++ !!
mocked
```

The first log line is from feature method `verify original native method`, the second one from `inject mock into utility class`. The other feature method does not yield any log output.

See? No Mockito or PowerMock, just normal Spock mocks without anything fancy after a small refactoring, making the dependency injectable.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Test
public void test1() {
  A a = PowerMockito.mock(A.class);
  PowerMockito.when(a.test()).thenReturn("test");
  PowerMockito.whenNew(A.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(a);

  boolean check = Util.test().equals("test");
  assert check
}
```

This has worked for me. I mocked the constructor's call.

Comment: Like Leonard said before, it is a JUnit test, not a Spock test. Your question is tagged "spock".